# How to send Click message to Tauri using PostMessageW

Tags: windows, rust, tauri

I'm developing an automation program. The goal is to use Tauri to load a web page, and then use Rust + windows-rs to send mouse click messages to the window for automation.

But I have a problem now, the messages sent to Tauri have no effect.

This is my code, the caption of the tauri window is `mhxyh5`, I try to find the hwnd of this window, and then call PostMessageW to send the message

```
fn main() {
    imitate_click();

    tauri::Builder::default()
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}


fn imitate_click() {
    println!("click");

    std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
        std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
        unsafe {
            let hwnd = get_webview_hwnd();
            let y = 10;
            let x = 100;
            let position = x << 16 | y;
            let lparam = Foundation::LPARAM(position);

            let res1 = WindowsAndMessaging::PostMessageW(
                hwnd,
                WindowsAndMessaging::WM_LBUTTONDOWN,
                Foundation::WPARAM(0),
                lparam,
            );

            let res2 = WindowsAndMessaging::PostMessageW(
                hwnd,
                WindowsAndMessaging::WM_LBUTTONUP,
                Foundation::WPARAM(0),
                lparam,
            );

            println!("res1: {}, res2: {}", res1.0, res2.0);
        }
    });
}


/// find tauri webview2 hwnd
fn get_webview_hwnd() -> Foundation::HWND {
    unsafe {
        let desk_hwnd = WindowsAndMessaging::GetDesktopWindow();
        let mut hwnd = WindowsAndMessaging::GetWindow(desk_hwnd, WindowsAndMessaging::GW_CHILD);
        while hwnd != Foundation::HWND(0) {
            let title = get_windows_title(hwnd);
            if title == "mhxyh5" {
                println!("hwnd: {}, title: {}", hwnd.0, title);
                let webview_hwnd =
                    WindowsAndMessaging::GetWindow(hwnd, WindowsAndMessaging::GW_CHILD);

                let webview_caption = get_windows_title(webview_hwnd);
                println!(
                    "webview_hwnd: {}, webview_caption: {}",
                    webview_hwnd.0, webview_caption
                );

                return webview_hwnd;
            }

            hwnd = WindowsAndMessaging::GetWindow(hwnd, WindowsAndMessaging::GW_HWNDNEXT);
        }

        Foundation::HWND(0)
    }
}
```

In order to verify whether a click has occurred on the window, I added a click event to the body

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  alert("click");
});
```

this is html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%;">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/styles.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Tauri App</title>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts" defer></script>
    <style>
      .logo.vite:hover {
        filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2em #747bff);
      }

      .logo.typescript:hover {
        filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2em #2d79c7);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="height: 100%;">
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know why, this code doesn't work, the log seen through printl indicates that the message is sent successfully, but the window can't get any response